# how to use link_to with ajax in rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I m using **Rails 3.2.1**. how to use link_to with remote=>true

**My Method in Controller**

```
def clickme
    @clk = "you click me"
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :layout=>false }
    end
  end
```

**My View**

In my **new.html.erb** file

```
<%= link_to "click here", {:action=>"clickme"}, {:remote => true, :id=>"clk"} %>

<div id="allclick">
    <%= render :partial => 'goclick'  %>
</div>
```

**_goclick.html.erb**

```
<%= @clk %>
```

**clickme.js.erb**

```
$("allclick").update("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "goclick")) %>");
```

On my web-page everything is fine when I click on click here link nothing change. But when I check Firebug console it shows me:

```
$("allclick").update("you click me");
```

**In My application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Help Me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `html` instead of `update`:

```
$("#allclick").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "goclick")) %>");
```

Comment: I am new to rails. Want to create a very basic web form where takes user input and convert it and display the result in the same page.
So I used the same workflow of the above, first it asked me for route for my method...so I added post "mymethodincontroller" to my routs configuration file so I resolved the missing rout error. But now when am clicking, no action is getting trigerred. no change at all is happening to the page...can anyone help me. @MiguelPing

Answer (score 3):

Use $("#allclick") not $("allclick"), you missed the "#" ;)

Comment: I used it. but still no output :(