# ajax and rails 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i'm trying to update a div in my index.html.erb file using Ajax in a rails app, but at this point i'm totally confused and totally frustrated by the lack of good explained tutorials(as far as i'm aware) on the web.

I currently have an index.html.erb file which amongst other things has the following block:

```
<table  border="1">
<% @dbs.each do |db| %>
<tr>
    <td ><%= link_to db, :action => :show, :db => db,  :remote => true %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<div id="collections">

</div>
```

my index controller just initliazies the @dbs var there and that's it, it doesn't have any respond_to blocks. I want to update the #collections div, but I'm struggling to understand how to go about doing this?

UPDATE - controller class:

Comment: I found the answer on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496172/how-to-use-link-to-with-ajax-in-rails-3-2-1

Answer (score 1):

You can create show.js.erb with this code :

```
comment_partial = '<%= escape_javascript(
  render('my_partial')
) %>';
$('collection').html(comment_partial);
```

Obviously, to use a partial is not mandatory. It's just JS with JQuery.

You should replace this code :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

By this :

```
render :format => :js
```

Comment: yes, i have a show.js.erb file which contains the following line: $("#collections").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@collections)) %>");  but when i click on one of the links in my index.html.erb it goes to the show view and doesn't stay on index and update the #div. Do I have to add anything in the index.html.erb #div block or is that fine (check in the question) ?

Comment: You should place render :format => :js in your show action, in your controller. If you to have js and html format for your show action you should have a respond_to block.

Comment: doesn't work! Do I have to add any javascript files, in the javascripts folder. Currently I have jquery.js and application.js. The head tag in my application.html.erb contains these lines:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
 
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Comment: could you show us your controller class? Wich version of rails do you use?

Comment: im using rails 3.2, find the controller class in the question!

Comment: it renders but on another page, i.e. doesn't stay on the index.html.erb and update the div, do I need to put anything in #div block!?

Comment: Strange... No you don't need to add anything in your div. Normaly, it send an ajax request and give and execute a JS file. Did you have an ajax request? Do you have an application.js.coffee with `#= require jquery` and `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile?

Comment: not sure if im issuing an ajax request, all i have is up there in the question! I have the gem 'jquery-rails' in my Gemfile, i have .js.coffee but there is no: #= require jquery  line in there

Comment: You can add `#= require jquery` in your application.js.coffee and you can remove your jquery.js file if you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile. You can you your browser's console to watch if there is an ajax request.

Comment: did all that, still doesn't work!? there is no Ajax request sent in the web console! I'm guessing maybe it's because, I'm missing any libraries in my javascripts folder!?!

Comment: You definitvely have a problem with your link... Does your project is open-source. Is it possible to view all sources?

Answer (score 0):

Make a show.js.erb file in the view folder for your controller, and write js code like

```
$("#collections").dostuff();
```